# Unable to get fields for a nested model form for a has_one relationship to show on the new view in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a BikeShops model:

```
class BikeShop < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, :as => :profile, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

And a Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I am trying to create a nested form in the bike_shops/new view.  Here is the code I have: in there:

```
<%= form_for(@bike_shop) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.label :name, 'Shop Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :street_address, 'Street Address' %>
        <%= f.text_field :street_address %>

        <%= f.label :city, 'City' %>
        <%= f.text_field :city %>

        <%= f.label :state, 'State' %>
        <%= f.text_field :state %>

        <%= f.label :zip_code, 'Zip Code' %>
        <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>

        <%= f.label :phone_number, 'Phone Number' %>
        <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>

        <%= f.label :website, 'Website' %>
        <%= f.text_field :website %>

        <% f.fields_for(:user) do |builder| %>

            <%= builder.label :first_name, 'First Name:' %>
            <%= builder.text_field :first_name %>

            <%= builder.label :last_name, 'Last Name:' %>
            <%= builder.text_field :last_name %>

            <%= builder.label :email, 'Email:' %>
            <%= builder.text_field :email %>

            <%= builder.label :password, 'Password:' %>
            <%= builder.password_field :password %>

            <%= builder.label :password_confirmation, 'Password Confirmation:' %>
            <%= builder.password_field :password_confirmation %>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.submit "Signup My Bike Shop", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

The fields for @bike_shop appear but the nested fields for the has_one @user do not appear.  Here is the code in the BikeShops controller:

```
class BikeShopsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @bike_shop = BikeShop.new
    @user = @bike_shop.build_user
  end
```

I was following this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) but can't get pass getting the fields for the nested form to show.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `<%=` erb tag in order to render it instead of just `<%`

```
<%= f.fields_for(:user) do |builder| %>
```

Comment: ha.  Tis always the simple things.  Thx for unfrustrating me.